# How to determine SciPy matrix "type" of a variable M

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there a method or a reliable way to determine if a given matrix `M` was created via `coo_matrix()` or `csc_matrix()` / `csr_matrix()`?

How could I write a method like this:

```
MATRIX_TYPE_CSC = 1
MATRIX_TYPE_CSR = 2
MATRIX_TYPE_COO = 3
MATRIX_TYPE_BSR = 4
...

def getMatrixType(M):
    if ...:
         return MATRIX_TYPE_COO
    else if ...:
         return MATRIX_TYPE_CSR
    return ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your matrix is a sparse matrix, you want the `.getformat()` method:

```
In [70]: s = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix([1,2,3])

In [71]: s
Out[71]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [72]: s.getformat()
Out[72]: 'coo'

In [73]: s = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1,2,3])

In [74]: s
Out[74]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [75]: s.getformat()
Out[75]: 'csr'
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems that SciPy provides a functional interface to check the sparse matrix type:

```
In [38]: import scipy.sparse as sps

In [39]: sps.is
sps.issparse        sps.isspmatrix_coo  sps.isspmatrix_dia
sps.isspmatrix      sps.isspmatrix_csc  sps.isspmatrix_dok
sps.isspmatrix_bsr  sps.isspmatrix_csr  sps.isspmatrix_lil
```

Example:

```
In [39]: spm = sps.lil_matrix((4, 5))

In [40]: spm
Out[40]: 
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [41]: sps.isspmatrix_lil(spm)
Out[41]: True

In [42]: sps.isspmatrix_csr(spm)
Out[42]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def getMatrixType(M):
    if isinstance(M, matrix_coo):
         return MATRIX_TYPE_COO
    else if isinstance(M, matrix_csr):
         return MATRIX_TYPE_CSR
```

The type of `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` is `type`, so `isinstance` works just fine.

but... why would you want to do this? It's not very pythonic.

Comment: Just looking at old questions here, but, the reason I wanted to do it was to support a Learning Model framework where this was useful and requested metadata to provide to the Data Scientists for use during model development.